# Method Generator in java

Tags: java, object, user-interface, methods

I am using [Kmax](http://www.sparrowcorp.com/products/software) to create a DAQ software. The philosophy of the GUI and the code is that every object on the GUI(radio buttons, check boxes, progress bars etc) has to have the same name with the relevant method. For instance an object named `BUTTON` is linked with the method `public void BUTTON(KmaxWidget widget){code}`.

My code is

```
import kmax.ext.*; 

public class Runtime implements KmaxRuntime {
    KmaxToolsheet tlsh; // Store a reference to the toolsheet environment
    KmaxHist hist1D;
    KmaxWidget checkBoxWidget;

    public void init(KmaxToolsheet toolsheet) {
        tlsh = toolsheet; // Save this reference for use in the toolsheet
        hist1D = tlsh.getKmaxHist("HIST1D");
        checkBoxWidget = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("CHECK_BOX_CALIB_METH");
        tlsh.getKmaxWidget("CHECK_BOX_CALIB_METH").setProperty("VALUE", "1");

    }

    public static boolean stringToBool(String s) {
    if (s.equals("1"))
        return true;
    if (s.equals("0"))
        return false;
    return true;
   }

    public void CalibInit(KmaxWidget widget, KmaxHist histo){
        histo.setUseXAxisCalibration(stringToBool(widget.getProperty("VALUE")));
        histo.update();

    }

    public void chooseCalib(){
    checkBoxWidget = tlsh.getKmaxWidget("CHECK_BOX_CALIB_METH");
    checkCalib(checkBoxWidget,hist1D);

}

    public void GO(KmaxToolsheet toolsheet){}
    public void SRQ(KmaxDevice device) {}
    public void HALT(KmaxToolsheet toolsheet) {}

} // End of the Runtime object
```

In the above code I have the check box `CHECK_BOX_CALIB_METH`. The problem arises when someone wants to create many objects;one has to create many methods. In the above code you can see what I am trying to do. I want to create a "main" method that will do every function that is needed and then another method will apply those functions to each object.

This code compiles without any errors, but the check box isn't working. So I was thinking if there is a way around this. For instance a method that will include "submethods" that will do the job! Or perhaps a method that will construct methods in a for loop for each radio button, check box, progress bar etc. Something like

```
for(int i=0; i<number_of_buttons ; i++){public void BUTTON_i(){code}}
```

The above code may look ridiculous but I don't know what else to think and I really want to avoid having one method for each button.

Is something like that possible or is there another way around this?

**EDIT**

For instance I have 6 methods that do exactly the same;they just have different names.

```
public void SET_CALIB_1(KmaxWidget widget) {
        double C0 = (getValueFrom("Ch2_1")*getValueFrom("En1_1")-getValueFrom("Ch1_1")*getValueFrom("En2_1"))/(getValueFrom("Ch2_1")-getValueFrom("Ch1_1")); 
        double C1 = (getValueFrom("En2_1")-getValueFrom("En1_1"))/(getValueFrom("Ch2_1")-getValueFrom("Ch1_1"));
        double C2 = 0;

        double[] coef = {C0, C1, C2};

        hist1.setXCalibration(coef);
        hist1.setUseXAxisCalibration(true);
        hist1.update();

    } // SET_CALIB_1
```

Is there a way to have a generator method to generate methods like the above?

Answer (score 0):

what are the design goals for this software?

reflection may be a much better way to get access to the members; and/or put all the components into an array for access.

I find that I tend to over-engineer things a lot; since I enjoy building things; but then they get way too complicated and don't work.

so I advise to take a walk (or trudge through the snow) and think about it some more.

Comment: The design goal is to avoid using a large number of methods for each object(buttons for instance). I can't think of a way to avoid that. Any ideas are more than welcome!